# Google Sheets Countunique in last n rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a row of names of restaurants in Google Sheets, but I only want to countunique() the last n cells in the column without having to constantly update the range of the function manually. This is all being done on a pivot table as well.

E.g.:

n = 5

***Raw Data***

- McDonald's
- Starbucks
- McDonald's
- McDonald's
- Chipotle
- Jack's
- Five Guys
- Chipotle

***Pivot Table***

- McDonald's | 1
- Starbucks_ | 0
- Chipotle__ | 2
- Jack's____ | 1
- Five Guys_ |1

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A:A, 
 "offset "&COUNTA(A:A)-B1), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({UNIQUE(A:A), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A:A), QUERY(QUERY(A:A, 
 "offset "&COUNTA(A:A)-B1), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label count(Col1)''"), 2, 0))*1}, 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way that I can make this in a pivot table? Whenever I try to use this as a custom equation in a pivot table it doesn't work. So essentially, I only want the VALUES put into a pivot table, and not have another row created with all the names.

Comment: pivot tables are not so flexible to be able to handle this task